# Define and do the following function using Mathematica 12. How can I do this?

Tags: functions

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Define and do the following function using Mathematica 12. How can I do this?

$$f[x]=|x|(-1 \le x \le 2),f[x+3]=f[x]+1$$

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by: |x|(−1≤x≤2). This would evaluate to: |x| True or |x| False. But I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use either of the following two:

```
f[x_] := Which[
  -1<=x<=2, Abs[x],
      x<-1, f[x+3]-1,
       x>2, f[x-3]+1];

f[x_] := Abs[Mod[x,3,-1]]+Quotient[x,3,-1];
```

Plot:

[image]

using `Plot[f[x],{x,-5,5}]`.

Comment: +1 Also, `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Abs[x], -1 <= x <= 2}, {f[x + 3] - 1, x < -1}, {f[x - 3] + 1, x > 2}}]`